# Unexpected truncation when copying data to empty string in C

Tags: c, arrays, gcc

I'm a C beginner and writing a program to copy a string from one character array to another:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void stringCopy(char s[], char t[]);

int main(void){
    char originalString[] = "pineapple"; // original string first
    char newVariable[] = ""; // empty string initialised and declared after
    stringCopy(newVariable,originalString);
    printf("Original string data: %s\n",originalString);
    printf("String in new variable: %s",newVariable);
    return 0;
}

void stringCopy(char s[], char t[]){
    int i=0;
    while((s[i] = t[i]) != '\0')
        i++;
}
```

What I'm curious about is that the above code ends up truncating the original string by one character at the front:

[image: unexpected output]

But the below code (with the order of **declaring/initialising arrays originalString and newVariable swapped around**) works as expected.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void stringCopy(char s[], char t[]);

int main(void){
    char newVariable[] = ""; // empty string initialised and declared first
    char originalString[] = "pineapple"; // original string data after
    stringCopy(newVariable,originalString);
    printf("Original string data: %s\n",originalString);
    printf("String in new variable: %s",newVariable);
    return 0;
}

void stringCopy(char s[], char t[]){
    int i=0;
    while((s[i] = t[i]) != '\0')
        i++;
}
```

[image: expected output]

**Why does it work when the empty string/character array is initialised first, but not the other way around?** It seems like the function is modifying the original string when it is initialised/declared before the new, empty string.

Literally all I did was swap the order in which I initialised/declared the arrays.

**(GCC/G++ compiler being used, does not give any warnings or errors for either case)**

Comment: You are invoking *undefined behavior*

Comment: What you are doing is undefined behavior, C don't have super feature that resize your array by magic.

Comment: You need to study how arrays work before you study strings. Basically, do you understand why `int a[] = {0}; int b[] = {1,2,3}; memcpy(a, b, sizeof(b));` will crash and burn? Because that's the very same problem.

Comment: Please done add your text messages as screenshot. You can simply copy and paste the pure text.

Comment: You could print out both arrays in your while loop to see exactly what they is in the array after each iteration. I would look through a few tutorials
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_strings.htm
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_arrays.htm

Answer (score 2):

You need to allocate space to fill the *empty* string.

An empty string like this,

```
char emptyString[] = "";
```

has a size of 1 byte, and you cannot resize it.

This should be read as "*declare an array and initialize it with the `""` constant*", resulting in an array of size `1` containing only the `null` terminator.

You need to allocate space by specifying the size explicitly

```
char emptyString[10] = "";
```

now this array allows copying into it.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck Well... how can you meaningfully change a C string with size 1, containing nothing more than a null terminator? Any change you do will mean that the data is a C string no longer.

Comment: @Stargateur Yes it does, I hate unclear code when there is no real performance or other kind of benefit.